# How to remove specific strings in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string `path = "foo/value/bar/value2"`, and I want to extract the value parts. Because the value can be null, I want to do this by removing the rest of the string.
There is no specific pattern, so the path can be anything, for example `"foo//value/value2"` (in that case, I must remove the "foo//" and then the "/".)

To make things clear, let's write it `path = foo + "value" + bar + "value"`.
foo and bar are *known*, *not null* string values, stored in an array `array = [foo, bar]`

The best solution for me is to separate my string with something like `path.split(regex)`, in order to have an array with the values, but I haven't found how to split a string from multiple sources.

Comment: Can you be more specific with another example.

Comment: `path = "/something/value/somethingelse/value2"``array = ["/something/","/somethingelse/"]`

Comment: how about `path.replace(/^\.*\//, "").split("/").filter((v,i) => i&1)`?

Comment: What do you want out of it ?

Comment: I want an array with [value, value2]

Comment: `There is no specific pattern, so the path can be anything` if there is no specific pattern, how should the code determine wich parts the values are, and wich ones to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var path = "foo/value/bar/value2";
var array = ['foo', 'bar'];
var reg = new RegExp(array.join("|"),"g");
console.log(path.split(reg));
```